# AWS Lambda Function : Failed to fetch secret arn:aws:secretsmanager

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-aurora

My AWS lambda function connected to Aurora database through 'AWS Secrets Manager Key' now its showing error 'Failed to fetch secret arn:aws:secretsmanager:us-east xxxxx'.

If I excite any query in AWS RDS query editor then all function will start work after some it will throw the same error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved this issue , though IAM role .
Create new Role IAM and added both resource and respect action  in IAM policy ( script manger and AWS Lambda ). This same Role using in my AWS Lambda serverless provider role access

> IAM Policy

```
{
"Version": "2012-10-17",
"Statement": [
    {
        "Sid": "VisualEditor10",
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Action": [
            "secretsmanager:GetSecretValue",
        ],
        "Resource": [
            "arn:aws:secretsmanager:us-east-2:*******:secret:rds-db-credentials/cluster-*************","
        ]
    }
  ]}
```

> Serverless YAML

```
 provider:
 name: aws 
 stage: ${opt:stage}
 runtime: nodejs12.x
 region: ${self:custom.config.app.region}
 stackTags:
    Account: ${self:custom.config.app.tags}

 role: ${self:custom.config.app.role}    <<== IAM ROLE NAME
```